# ExtJs4: Best practice of using several Ext.grid.Panel components with big data

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4, bigdata

I'm using one Ext.grid.Panel component with hundreds of rows loaded at a time.
Data is loading via Ajax transport.
Now i need to add more grids with such amount of rows (hundreds at a time, tens of thousands in DB table).
I need to position these grids on different tabs. Only one grid will be opened at a moment.

My question is what to do with grids with loaded rows which are left on used tabs? I'm afraid not to overload browser RAM in this situation.

Comment: I consider there are two ways to do this: 1: destroy grid component after changing tab, and then create it again when this tab is chosen again. 2: just empty specific grid storage and load it occasionaly again. But it is only my thoughts, and what about experienced developers decision?